# Anyone else working in Cylance environment - it blocks many of the VBA lines of code

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have several ms access databases that contain many lines of VBA code. All this worked fine up until a few months ago when network security software called Cylance was installed. This Cylance prevents many different types scripts and programs from running. Cylance uses something called a 'Whitelist' folder from which you should be able execute code that is known to be safe.
In the Whitelist folder I have database, when I try to run code that I know worked a few months ago I get a runtime error 13 Type Mismatch. However there is no mismatch and this code executed fine in the past.
Is anybody else working in Cylance environment? Have you had Error 13 Type Mismatch? How to fix it?

The main thing I've tried is working from the Whitelist folder, I don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 1):

I tested Cylance and I had to uninstall it because it had too many false positives. Not even with VBA code. It was blocking legitimate applications that we needed. I could whitelist an application but then I needed to whitelist it again every time the application was updated. If you are developing software you would have the same problem. You would have to whitelist every build. I can see how this would cripple your Access development. Cylance keeps you safe from VBA attacks in a way that other AV solutions do not but the trade off is that it also blocks VBA code that you know is safe. Open a ticket with their support team. Good luck.